# Strong minimum principle for maximal plurisubharmonic functions

Tags: complex-geometry, potential-theory, cv.complex-variables, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose $u$ is a bounded maximal plurisubharmonic function in a bounded domain $D \in \Bbb C^n$. If $u$ is $C^2$ one can see that $u$ cannot have a local strict minimum inside $D$. Is there an analog of this result, when $u$ is not $C^2$-smooth? Any counterexamples?

Comment: I think I got this one.